Catholic litany or rite of supplication - in the extreme collective hardships?
Our local Church (Eastern Europe) has tradition to recite the following Litany (GPT translation in English):

Litany of Supplication – Holy God Holy God, Holy Mighty God, Holy
Eternal God, have mercy on us! From plague, famine, war, and fire,
deliver us, O Lord and God! From an evil and sudden death, save us, O
Lord and God! Govern and sustain Your holy Church, we beseech You, O
Lord and God! Grant us the grace of true repentance, we beseech You, O
Lord and God! Strengthen and sustain us in Your holy service, we
beseech You, O Lord and God! Protect and bless our homeland, we
beseech You, O Lord and God! Grant and sustain the fruits of the
earth, we beseech You, O Lord and God! We, sinners, beseech You,
merciful God, hear us, O Lord and God! Jesus, Jesus, Jesus, have mercy
on us! Mary, Mary, Mother of God, pray to God for us!

It is recited very rarely, the last time it was done - during the gravest hours of Covid pandemic.
I wanted to ask - what is the English and Latin translation it? Judging from the words, it can be one of the most solemn prayer (rite) of extreme strength. So - maybe there are the official texts and indications for it?
p.s. Less than 2 hours ago Biden authorized the long range strikes to Russia. There has been very clear plans what will be done in response to them. So, the supplications can be only thing that is left.
